# Wont leave while loop

Tags: python, debugging, python-3.x, error-handling

I am a bit of a rookie programmer but i can usually spot things like this so i am thinking its a logic error rather than a syntax one. So i was wondering if you could use your fresh eyes to fix the error. The code is:

```
database = open("database.txt", "r+")
databaselist = database.readlines()
length = len(databaselist)
for i in range (length):
    database.readline()

Continue = True
while Continue == True:
    Title = input("Enter title of book: ")
    Author = input("Enter author of book: ")
    Genre = input("Enter genre of book: ")
    Location = input("Enter the location of the book: ")
    TitleWrite = Title + "\n"
    AuthorWrite = Author + "\n"
    GenreWrite = Genre + "\n"
    LocationWrite = Location + "\n"
    database.write(str(TitleWrite))
    database.write(str(AuthorWrite))
    database.write(str(GenreWrite))
    database.write(str(LocationWrite))
    Continue2 = input("Would you like to continue? Y or N: ")
    if Continue2 == "n":
        Contine = False
        database.close()
```

Comment: Typo `Contine` is a different parameter than `Continue`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `break` statement to break out of a loop. Using this, you can get rid of the `Continue` variable:

```
while True: # "infinite" loop that you will break out of
    title = ...
    author = ...

    response = input('Would you like to continue? Y or N: ')
    if response.lower() == 'n':
        database.close()
        break # break out of the "infinite" loop
```

(Note that in Python, the norm is to have lowercase variable names).

Comment: Thanks ill try it and i am sure it will work.

PS - I know that its normal to do .lower() but i removed it when debugging and just didnt put it back in